# Detect and remove silence from audio file using gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer

Is there any way by which we can detect and remove silence from an audio file using GStreamer.

Currently, by using `level` I am able to find the start and end time of silence present in the audio file but how do I remove this silence and produce an output which doesn't have silence in it. I tried using `gst_element_seek` but no luck there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a removesilence element in gstreamer-plugins-bad, perhaps it is what you want.

**Edit: adding example**

```
gst-launch-1.0 autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! removesilence remove=true ! fakesink silent=false -v
```

This launch line will print data to the screen whenever removesilence output buffers, it will be capturing audio from the microphone of your system. It will only output audio when some noise is detected.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this plugin but i'm not able to get correct output, can you provide some example for this plugin